# How do you get the username of a roblox account using Python Requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

hope you are all doing well. This question is a bit more random than others I have asked. I am making a bot that extracts every username of the first 600,000,000 accounts on the platform Roblox, and loads it into a list.

This is my problem. I am using requests to get to the account page, but I can't find out how to extract the username from that page. I have tried using headers and inspect element but they don't work. If anyone has some suggestions on how to complete this, please help. Also, I am extraordinarily bad at network programming, so I may have made a noob mistake somewhere. Code is attached below.

```
import requests
users = []
for i in range(1, 600000001):
    r = requests.get("https://web.roblox.com/users/{i}/profile".format(i=i))
    print(r.status_code)
    if r.status_code == 404:
        users.append('Deleted')
        continue

    
    print(r.headers.get('username'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to know that before working on the scraping, you have some errors in the code:
First of all in the 4th line if you want to use the `.format` command to insert values in a string you only have to insert the `{}`; so you should write:

```
r = requests.get("https://web.roblox.com/users/{}/profile".format(i))
```

And later you should remove `continue` from your code

But before doing anything you have to try the link be sure it's working, so copy the link, past it on your browser and remove i and add a number.
If it works you can go on with the code, if not you have to find another link to access to the page you want.

Eventually, to take the elements from the html page you have to use `r.content`.
But before continuing with coding you have to `print(r.content)`.
You will see a long dict full of elements but you don't have to be afraid of it:
you have  to search the value that interest you, and see how it's called, and you will be able to call that value writing

```
`<name_of_variable> = r.content['<name_of_the_value>']`
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! I will let you know if it works.